# Minimal functionally complete operator sets with XOR

Tags: boolean-algebra

What's the minimal functionally complete operator sets which contains XOR?

Since AND, OR and NOT are a functionally complete set, I have to find a set of operators that can build these three operators.

I completed the exercise this way:
Set = {XOR, AND}

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fbspIh.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Is my solution correct? Can someone dimostrate why this is the smallest functionally complete operator set or why it's not (and post the solution)?

Comment: I think it's also {XOR, OR} is a valid set, because XOR is still used to obtain NOT, and with NOT+OR can obtain AND

Comment: there are two things: minimal and complete. It looks like you have demonstrated completeness. Are you sure about minimal-ness? Give it some thought. Side note: pin 1 in your XOR gate cannot be left unconnected.

Comment: @mkeith, I think that's not "pin 1", that's a pin connected to a logical "1".

Comment: @ThePhoton, I think you are right. My bad.

Comment: @mkeith exactly, it's connected to a logical "1". I'm quite sure it's the smallest set I can create, but I don't know any may to prove that in a formal way.

Comment: Is this homework? I have been assuming it is. Anyway, the only way to make it smaller would be to remove the AND gate. Can you make AND using only XOR? Or can you prove it is impossible to make AND using only XOR? Did you try, at all?

Comment: It's not an homework. It was an exercise I found on the textbook I currently use in my Computer Architecture course, a very optional exercise. Most of the topics on this argument you can find on the net is about completeness (this helped me with the first parte: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/220271/functional-completeness-of-textor-text-xor-text-xnor) but no one talks about minimalism. I think I can prove I cannot build AND using XORs, but how is it related to minimalism?

Comment: I played around with it a few minutes. Initially I thought I would be able to make AND from XOR. Turns out that it is impossible, because XOR is not functionally complete by itself. It seems that the only avenue of proof would be to invoke Post's Theorem. It is a bit too much for me to dig into, but maybe you will be motivated enough to do it:
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Functional_completeness#Characterization_of_functional_completeness

Comment: XOR must be included (given). XOR and AND is only two elements (inspection). To be more minimal, you would have to remove AND (consequence of previous statements). The only way to remove AND and maintain completeness is to implement AND using only XOR. Thus, stating AND cannot be implemented using only XOR is exactly equivalent to saying that {AND, XOR} is the minimal set containing XOR. It may not be the ONLY minimal set, but it is one minimal set.

Comment: @mkeith I think you should write that as an answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

XOR must be included (this is given).
XOR and AND can be shown to be complete. (OP has done this)
XOR and AND is only two elements (by inspection).
To be more minimal, you would have to remove AND.
The only way to remove AND and maintain completeness is to implement AND using only XOR.

Thus, stating AND cannot be implemented using only XOR is exactly equivalent to saying that {AND, XOR} is the minimal set containing XOR. It may not be the ONLY minimal set, but it is one minimal set.

To generate a rigorous proof, see the work of Emil Post. He apparently discovered the properties necessary for completeness. So if you can use his theorem, you can show that XOR is not complete by itself using his work.